# How to perform a select in FastReport to only show the last record in the report?

Tags: sql, fastreport

I am creating a report in **FastReport 6.9.2** and the `LIMIT` command does not work in FastReport and I would like to know how
I can put the last record of the table in my report,
thank you.

```
SELECT T1.COD_PRODUTO
FROM
    TPRODUTO T1
WHERE
(    T1.COD_PRODUTO LIKE :CODIGO)
GROUP BY T1.COD_PRODUTO
ORDER BY T1.COD_PRODUTO DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Do you want just that T1.COD_PRODUTO column?

Comment: Yes, correct I do

Comment: `select max(T1.COD_PRODUTO) from TPRODUTO T1 WHERE T1.COD_PRODUTO LIKE :CODIGO`